# SQL derived attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make the Room_Status in Table 1 (ROOM) table into a derived attribute base on the check_in and check_out date Table 2 (Booking Records) table, but I don't know if it is possible to determine the room status dynamically based on the check_in/check_out date in table 2 , eg. The room with room_no 103 suppose to be unavailable for day 19/02/2020 to 20/02/2020 because its already booked by someone else , so the room status will be displayed as unavailable or N, after date 20/02/2020 the room will be available again.

Another extra thing is that I want to calculate the days available for each room based on the table 2 check_in and check_out date eg. room 103 will be available for only 1 day if it is booked on 19/02/2020 to 20/02/2020 after one day which is 22/02/2020 the room is booked by another customer, how should I calculate the days available...

Table 1 (ROOM)

```
ROOM_NO ROOM_STATUS  ('Y' represent 'Available' , 'N' represent 'Unavailable')
======= ============
     1  Y            
     2  Y            
     3  Y            
     4  Y            
     5  Y            
     6  Y            
     7  Y            
     8  Y            
     9  Y            
    10  Y     
more rooms.....
```

Table 2 (Booking Records)

```
BOOKING_ID CHECK_IN   CHECK_OUT  SPECIAL_REQ          CANCEL_REASON        DATE_BOOK     ROOM_NO GUEST
========== ========   =========  ===========          =============        =========     ======= =====
     1     19/02/2020 20/02/2020 Prepare hot bath tub                      17/02/2020        103 980315070652
                                 when check in.

     2     20/05/2020 27/05/2020 Prepare scented                           10/05/2020         10 C00001549
                                 candle and meal when
                                 check in

     3     21/05/2020 23/05/2020 Prepare latest news                       10/05/2020          9 C00001894
                                 paper in room

     4     20/05/2020 24/05/2020 Prepare hot bath tub                      17/05/2020        124 980315070652
                                 when check in.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following, something like this? Strictness of the inequality (<,<=) will depend on how you want to define available on a given day.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Room_No,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   ( SELECT 1
                       FROM Booking_Records BR2
                      WHERE BR.room_no = BR2.room_no
                        AND CURRENT_DATE >= BR2.Check_In
                        AND CURRENT_DATE < BR2.Check_Out
                   ) THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
        END AS Currently_Available
  FROM Booking_Records BR
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the rooms from the `booking_records` table that are available on `2020-05-22`:

```sql
SELECT room_no,
       CASE COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN DATE '2020-05-22' BETWEEN CHECK_IN AND CHECK_OUT
              AND  cancel_reason IS NULL
              THEN 1
              END
            )
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END AS room_status_20200522
FROM   booking_records
GROUP BY room_no
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE booking_records ( BOOKING_ID, CHECK_IN, CHECK_OUT, CANCEL_REASON, ROOM_NO ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-02-19', DATE '2020-02-20', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(50) ), 103 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-05-20', DATE '2020-05-27', NULL,  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-05-21', DATE '2020-05-23', NULL,   9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2020-05-20', DATE '2020-05-24', NULL, 124 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ROOM_NO | ROOM_STATUS_20200522
> ------: | :-------------------
>       9 | N                   
>     103 | Y                   
>      10 | N                   
>     124 | N
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ea06170c568629af20cb1fdf052e33d)*

Answer (score 0):

So, You need to fetch room status and number of day availability after room is free.

I am considering that `booking_records` table can contain more than one reservation for the same `room_no`.

Following query will give you desired details as of `sysdate`.

```
Select r.room_no,
       Max(Case when b.bookin_id is not null then'N' else 'Y' end) as booking_status,
       Min(bn.check_in - coalesce(b.check_out,sysdate)) as available_days
  From rooms r
  Left Join booking_records b
    On b.room_no = r.room_no
   And sysdate between b.check_in and b.check_out
  Left join booking_records bn
    On bn.room_no = r.room_no
   And bn.check_in > sysdate
Group by r.room_no
```